# Blocking behavior of channel receive operator in goroutine call

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

```
go DelegateWork(mr, <-mr.impl.readyWorkers, jobArgs)
```

In the above example, would the channel receive operator cause the caller or the called goroutine to block?

Comment: Yes, of course. How could it not block? What would the semantics be if this would be somehow non-blocking? Why should that not be blocking?

Comment: Well, you're passing values, aren't you, so obviously you're going to have to wait until a value was read from the channel prior to actually calling the function/starting the new routine.

Answer (score 7):

[Spec: Go statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements)

> **The function value and parameters are evaluated as usual in the calling goroutine**, but unlike with a regular call, program execution does not wait for the invoked function to complete. Instead, the function begins executing independently in a new goroutine.

So if `<-mr.impl.readyWorkers` blocks, it blocks the caller goroutine, before the new goroutine is launched.